# Change Web APi Root Directory

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, iis-8.5

I have a Web Api Application that performs a file upload to Amazon S3 when I POST a file path to it. How do I change the root directory this file path is relative to? Right now, if I send `myVideo.flv` as the file path, my app tries to find the file to upload at `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\myVideo.flv`. I'd like it to look for the file at `c:\MyApp\files\myVideo.flv`. Is this something I change in the app config or iis?

Here is my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage move([FromBody] Models.Request request)
{
    string videopath = request.videopath;

    try
    {
        PutObjectRequest putVideo = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = WebApiConfig.AWSVideoBucket,
            Key = videopath,
            FilePath = videopath,
            ContentType = "video/flv"
        };

        PutObjectResponse videoResponse = WebApiConfig.AWSclient.PutObject(putVideo);

        if (videoResponse.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "File not found: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Map a directory that points to your desired root folder under your applications root

Comment: How do I do that? Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS, Expand Sites and find your web site, Right click on the web site and select "Add Virtual Directory". This directory can be pointed to anywhere on the machine. In your app, you would read/write to this virtual directory under the root of the application. Also be mindful of permissions, to make sure the users accessing the site have proper permissions to that virtual directory.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't seem to do anything. Anyway, it looks like there already is a virtual directory for my site in my applicationHost.config file that is pointing to the correct directory. It still seems to be looking for the file in the inetsrv directory I mentioned.

Comment: is `request.videopath` an absolute path or is it a relative path? an example?

Comment: Relative. It would be a string like 'myVideo.flv' or 'files/myVideo.flv'.

Comment: Have you tried hard coding `c:\MyApp\files\myVideo.flv` for the `FilePath` just to see if your can pick up the file from the correct location? Obviously, this wouldn't be a solution but it'll help with debugging the issue

Comment: Yes hard coding works fine. In fact, currently I have my desired root directory hard-coded in my Web.config and I'm just grabbing it from there and adding it to the request.videopath. But yeah it seems like there should be a way for me to have the app use this directory automatically.